Dropdown menu doesn't appear when I pass the mouse on navbar
Good day,
I am trying to create a dropdown menu on my freshly new website but cannot find the reason as to why it does not appear.
It should appear under "About" but when I click on it nothing appears!
Could someone help me?
Maybe the problem has a link with the display:none// display:block?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #101010;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.inner_header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 40%;
}

.logo_container h1 {
  color: bisque;
  font-family: "Whisper", cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.menu_navbar {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_navbar ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_navbar ul li {
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu_navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: bisque;
}

.active,
.menu_navbar ul li:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sub_menu_navbar_1 {
  display: none;
}

.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner_header">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <h1>Céramique & Porcelaine</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="menu_navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <div class="sub_menu_navbar_1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Artist</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>



Thank you in advance!

.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 : Here You are selecting .sub_menu_navbar_1 inside  .menu_navbar ul li (on hover), which is not the case, .sub_menu_navbar_1 is outside/is not a child of .menu_navbar ul li.

The problem is here,
.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 ul{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    
}

According to your styling rule to trigger the hover effect on the sub_menu_navbar the element needs to inside li element. Like below,
      <li>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <div class="sub_menu_navbar_1">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">The Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Artist</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

I hope this helps.

The dropdown menu should be nested within the li element that triggers it, but in your code, the .sub_menu_navbar_1 is placed outside of any li element. This can cause the CSS hover selector to not work as intended.
The position: relative; on the li ensures that the absolutely positioned .sub_menu_navbar_1 is placed relative to the li itself, not the entire page or another parent element.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #101010;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #101010;
}

.inner_header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo_container {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 40%;
}

.logo_container h1 {
  color: bisque;
  font-family: "Whisper", cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

.menu_navbar {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_navbar ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  color: bisque;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu_navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: bisque;
}

.active,
.menu_navbar ul li:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sub_menu_navbar_1 {
  display: none;
}

.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.menu_navbar ul li:hover .sub_menu_navbar_1 ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}
.sub_menu_navbar_1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 0; 
}
<header>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="inner_header">
      <div class="logo_container">
        <h1>Céramique & Porcelaine</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="menu_navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <div class="sub_menu_navbar_1">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Artist</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



